# How can I query the version of the node using the APIs?

Tags: cardano-node, api

I want to know the version of a node using API.
I know I can use the CLI to know the version, but can't I use the API?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/createByronWalletMigrationPlan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `cardano-cli` but you can just run:

```
cardano-node --version
```

or

```
cardano-cli --version
```

without having to stop the `node`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I need to know the version using an API that can be called externally over the network, is there one? (rest, graphql, etc, excluding cli).

Comment: I think you should add a feature request on the `cardano-node` github repo.